# Permutations and COMBINATION divisibility test

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The number of five digit numbers that can be formed using all the digits $0, 1, 3, 6, 8$ which are

(A) divisible  by $4$ is $30$

(B) greater than $30,000$ and divisible by $11$ is $12$

(C) smaller than $60,000$ when digit $8$ always appears at ten's place is $6$

(D) between $30,000$ and $60,000$ and divisible by $6$ is $18$.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you please describe the question with more details, defining things, talking what you think about the problem (what you've tried) and formatting it properly using MathJax? You should read the complete Tour page before asking a question: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: can you reuse the digits or you can only use each one once?

Comment: Can use each once

Comment: Do you have a question? Your points A, B, & D, are correct, but C is wrong. There are 12 such numbers: 10386, 10683, 13086, 13680, 16083, 16380, 30186, 30681, 31086, 31680, 36081, 36180

Comment: @PM2Ring I am unsure wheather (A) is correct. it cannot start with $0$ and has to end with $8$, right? the rest of the digits can be permutated. I think its less than $30$ or?

Comment: A _is_ correct. It doesn't have to end in 8. Here are the 30 solutions. 10368, 10836, 13068, 13608, 13680, 13860, 16308, 16380, 18036, 18360, 30168, 30816, 31068, 31608, 31680, 31860, 36108, 36180, 38016, 38160, 61308, 61380, 63108, 63180, 80136, 80316, 81036, 81360, 83016, 83160

Comment: Correct answers are option ABD

Comment: @PM2Ring ah, true.